# Как это понять?

Tags: php, framework

> лучше сторонний фреймворк и **бизнесс-логика отделенная** от фреймворка.

[источник](https://toster.ru/q/361767)

Примеры не надо , просто объяснения , как можно отделить одно от другого ?
Логику от зависимости фреймворка

Прошу не минусовать - а объяснить

Comment: А почему бы не спросить автора ответа напрямую, что он имел в виду? Регистрация на тостере вроде была свободная?

Comment: @Ипатьев блин я больше сдешней публике доверяю - чем тостеру ,

Comment: Дело не в доверии. Здесь вопрос про то, что там себе думает конкретный индивидуум. А телепатов тут не больше, чем на тостере.

Comment: @Ипатьев ты ж как phpшник - наверняка понял о чём речь ?к примеру php не мой конёк , но когда речь идёт о photoshop или corel draw или css3 или х.з о чём ещё  пойму

Comment: Нет, я не понял. И пхп здесь не при чем - подобный вопрос имеет отношение к любому языку. По мне эта фраза - масло масляное. 100% проектов пишутся так как там написано. Я не представляю, как сделать наоборот - впихнуть бизнес-логику в фреймворк.

Comment: @Ипатьев  вот это я ожидал , потому собственно и появился этот вопрос , напишите ответ - он будет лучшим

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бизнес-логика это собственно логика вашего приложения. Фреймворк это набор библиотек, осуществляющий стандартные рутинные операции.

Например, если вы пишете приложение для общественной бани, то бизнес-логика будет содержать описание профиля пользователя, расписания, поиска свободных мест для бронирования и т.д. При этом оно может использовать фреймворк для таких вещей как общение с базой, работа с параметрами запроса, dependency injection, работа с почтой и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать понятие "**лучше**" здесь неправильно (это смахивает на навязывание личных интересов), в каком-то случае будут правильнее писать свои костыли, в каком-то использовать фреймворк. Есть определенные причины на тот или иной случай, это дело вкуса каждой команды и **требований к задаче**, на этом останавливаться не будем.

Понятие **отделенной бизнес-логики** основано на уменьшении связанности. Это принцип проектирования многоуровневой архитектуры, при которой вы общаетесь с компонентами фреймворка через интерфейсы, тем самым, делая свой проект независимым от использования стороннего программного обеспечения. Никто не говорит, что фреймворк будет сменить легко при использовании интерфейсов, но это будет сделать проще, чем без них.

**Предположим**, у нас есть DI контейнер, встроенный в фреймворк, вы можете напрямую использовать его, а можете через абстрагирование и собственные методы реализовать получение определенных сервисов, и предположим, когда будете устанавливать новую версию фреймворка, и у него поменяется метод получения c `$di->getService("myservice")` на `$di->get("myservice")` вам будет нужно сделать лишь изменение в своем классе (*например,* ApplicationContext). Вы свой интерфейс врятли будете менять, а разработчики стороннего ПО могут прийти к новой конвенции наименования.

Бизнес логика должна быть на одном уровне, фреймворк и сторонние библиотеки на другом. Это идеальная архитектура и отклонения от этой архитектуры будут, потому что реализация абстракций и их поддержка под новые задачи требует приличного времени, но к этому следует стремиться, чтобы легко заменять любые компоненты и уменьшить связанность, но фанатизм здесь не нужен.

Примером подобного проектирования является луковая архитектура, гексагональная архитектура, и любая нормальная архитектура основанная на слоях.

[image: Многоуровневая архитектура]

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто, бизнес-логику реализовать на простых PHP-классах (POPO - Plain Old PHP Object), никак не зависящих от фреймворка. Просто нужно понимать, что есть бизнес-логика, а что логика приложения. Бизнес-логика оперирует понятиями предметной области, например, в случае какого-то магазина это понятия "покупатель", "товар", "заказ", "счёт" и т. п., в случае игры "персонаж", "инвентарь", "карта" и т. д. Бизнес-логика ничего не знает о базах данных (если конечно, вы не разрабатываете что-то вроде phpmyadmin), файлах, контроллерах и вьюхах, она не знает как хранятся её сущности, для неё в идеале они живут в оперативной памяти вечно, пока она не решит их удалить навсегда.

Часто используемый фреймворк не позволяет полностью избавиться в бизнес-логике от зависимостей от фреймворка, заставляя, например, писать что-то вроде class Order extends Model, чтобы обеспечить сохранение заказа в базе данных, тогда нужно максимально абстрагироваться от этого факта - унаследовались и забыли (в рамках этого класса и других классов бизнес-логики) что есть методы типа save или delete - их должен вызывать только контроллер (в терминах MVC), но не бизнес-логика.